# Undefine all inactive domains

Tags: libvirt

I have multiple inactive domains in libvirt and I want to delete them all:

```
# virsh list --inactive
 Id Name                 State
----------------------------------
  - instance-0000000c    shut off
  - instance-0000000f    shut off
  - instance-00000010    shut off
```

Is there a simple way to tell libvirt to delete all inactive domains, or do I have to manually do:

```
# virsh undefine instance-0000000c
# virsh undefine ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$ virsh list --inactive | grep instance | cut -d " " -f 4 | xargs -n 1 virsh undefine
```

If you want to review that list before killing them:

```
$ virsh list --inactive | grep instance | cut -d " " -f 4 > inactive_domains
$ vi inactive_domains
```

Then if everything looks good:

```
$ cat inactive_domains | xargs -n 1 virsh undefine
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a much cleaner way to do it:

```
virsh list --inactive --name | xargs -r -n 1 virsh undefine
```

Be careful, it will removall all. Also it will not fail when there is nothing to clean up.